# Changing positive(+) and negative(-) signs to integers in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following column:

```
A
+
+
-
+
-
```

How do I convert this column into integer values. So that I could multiply it to other numerical values?

Therefore, all '+' would be replaced by 1 and '-' by -1.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to replace `+` with `1`, and `-` with `-1`, right? If that's the case, please update your question so it's clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.A = df.A.map({'+': 1, '-': -1})
```

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you could just use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
>>> df
   A
0  +
1  +
2  -
3  +
4  -

new_df = df.replace({'A':{'+':1, '-':-1}})

>>> new_df
   A
0  1
1  1
2 -1
3  1
4 -1
```

Answer (score 6):

using apply:

*assumes that only `+` and `-` values are in the column*

```
df['A'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: 1 if x == '+' else -1)
```

using string concatenation & casting:

```
df['A'] = (df.A + '1').astype(int)
```

using string equality & casting:

```
df['A'] = (df.A == '+').astype(int)*2-1
```

Answer (score 3):

Some possible ways may be using `add` to add string of `1` and converting to `int` with `astype` :

```
df['A'] = df.A.add('1').astype(int)
```

Or using `lambda` for same purpose as above:

```
df['A'] = df.A.apply(lambda row: int(row + '1'))
```

Answer (score 3):

### `searchsorted`

```
df.assign(A=1 - np.array(['+']).searchsorted(df.A) * 2)

   A
0  1
1  1
2 -1
3  1
4 -1
```

---

### Succinct

```
df.assign(A=df.A.eq('-').mul(2).rsub(1))

   A
0  1
1  1
2 -1
3  1
4 -1
```